# .NET - A fast lightweight persistent key-value storage

Tags: .net, database, storage, key-value-store

I'm looking for a persistent key-value storage for .NET. The requirements are:

- Storage is used for objects that are identified by strings and have several optional (named) properties with values that are just byte arrays. For an SQL solution I would model it as one string -> id table, and several id -> blob tables.
- The expected amount of data is several megabytes (more than 10 Mb is currently unlikely, but scaling up to 100 Mb would be a nice bonus)
- Lightweight - preferably single-assembly, definitely without external applications
- Reads are more frequent than writes, at least by a factor of 100.
- Fast read/write access - I expect in-memory storage and lazy writes on the updates to the data; I can periodically spawn async writes myself, bonus points if the storage does it.
- Atomic I/O - the database should not break if the process is terminated in the middle of writing; otherwise the data is not critical, i.e. no additional redundancy is needed.

Currently I think that SQLite will work here; however it seems to be a slight overkill - I only need key-value storage, not full SQL support. I've also heard of bdb, and of libdb-dotnet binding - it seems to be more lightweight, but I don't know the performance/consistency characteristics.

Can anyone recommend something here? Additional references are welcome (i.e. it would be awesome if there's something in .NET Framework that can do the job), as well as experiences with SQLite or libdb-dotnet (or bdb in general) or home-grown solution, if it was painless.

Comment: Sounds to me using any kind of database would be overkill for this, with just 10mb why not read/write everything at once to and from disk? (it's not like it's taking all that much memory)

Comment: @Doggett, that sounds like re-inventing the database, if the proposed application is non-trivial.

Comment: @Doggett, the problem is that writing full DB on every update is going to be slow, and there's no single flush point (i.e. I can't write full DB on app exit because app can be terminated prematurely); I'll have to support partial flushes, and make them atomic - this is the only non-trivial thing about this, I guess.

Comment: Have you checked ZoneTree?

https://github.com/koculu/ZoneTree

It is several times faster than Facebook's RocksDB and hundreds of times faster than SQLite.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps have a look at http://ravendb.net/. It stores JSON documents in a key-value storage, but with great .NET object support.

From your explanation of your needs, you could also look into just utilizing it's managed storage engine, "Raven.Munin", which is a single assembly.